# How to store a field of 1x5 structure in a variable(array) in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, field

I want to store all values of a field of a 1x5 structure in a variable(array) in MATLAB... See the attached screenshots for better understanding.

[image: Script]

[image: Workspace Variables]

[image: Structure Data/Content]

Answer (score 0):

### Dot-Indexing by Field Name and Formatting as an Array

To access the specific field dot indexing by the structure, `I` by the field name in this case `Overshoot` can be done. To format this as an array the square brackets `[]` can be used to convert the cell array to a row vector. To convert this to a column-vector like how it appears in structure, `I` we can transpose this by using the `.'` term.

```
Overshoot = [I.Overshoot].';
```

---

[image: Accessing Structure Field]

### Test Script:

```
%Random structure to test%
I(5).RiseTime = [];
I(5).SettlingTime = [];
I(5).SettlingMin = [];
I(5).SettlingMax = [];
I(5).Overshoot = [];
I(5).Undershoot = [];
I(5).Peak = [];
I(5).PeakTime = [];

%Filling the random structure%
for Index = 1: 5
    I(Index).RiseTime = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).SettlingTime = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).SettlingMin = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).SettlingMax = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).Overshoot = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).Undershoot = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).Peak = rand(1,1);
    I(Index).PeakTime = rand(1,1);
end

Overshoot = [I.Overshoot].';
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**